# Swing can't use custom fonts with HTML markup

Tags: java, swing

When using a custom font that was created with the Font.createFont method (and the font is not installed on the OS), swing text components will use the default font if there are any HTML tags:

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.File;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TestFont
{
    public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
    {
        Font customFont = Font.createFont(Font.TRUETYPE_FONT, new File("Manaspace.ttf")).deriveFont(12f);
        Font courier = Font.decode("Courier").deriveFont(12f);

        JFrame win = new JFrame("TestFont");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 2, 10, 10));

        JLabel label1 = new JLabel("Courier");
        label1.setFont(courier);
        panel.add(label1);

        JLabel label2 = new JLabel("<html>Courier with HTML</html>");
        label2.setFont(courier);
        panel.add(label2);

        JLabel label3 = new JLabel("Manaspace");
        label3.setFont(customFont);
        panel.add(label3);

        JLabel label4 = new JLabel("<html>Manaspace with HTML</html>");
        label4.setFont(customFont);
        panel.add(label4);

        win.setContentPane(panel);
        win.pack();
        win.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        win.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Gives the output:

[image]

Notice that the bottom right label does not use the manaspace font.

Comment: Try using `GraphicsEnvironement.registerFont(Font)` ..

Comment: @AndrewThompson : brilliant. Care to copy paste that into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before a custom `Font` can be accessed 'indirectly' it must be registered with the `GraphicsEnvironment`. Something like:

```
ge.registerFont(font);
```

Comment: In most cases : GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().registerFont(font);